# getting last day from next month

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get last day from next month in this select.

```
select (last_day(month from :date+1)||'.'||
       (extract(month from :date)+1)||'.'||
       extract(year from :date))
  from dual;
```

Everything is ok with month and year but I have a problem with last day function.

Comment: What is the problem. What is your current output and what do you expect.

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(
   ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(:date, 'DD.MM.YY')), 1), 'DD') from dual .
with this i can get last day , but when i try to put this in first select in last_day function i get error. i need to get last day of the next month of :date input.

Comment: @JSapkota  this is what I get . invalid extract field for extract source

Comment: Yes its working but I need to get just day not whole date. i need to get output od dd.mm.yyyy .
When I try to insert your code in my last day function it doesnt work

Comment: `select extract(day from last_day(add_months(sydate,1))) from dual;`?

Comment: This is good, but when i cut it in my (look up in the select ) first line i get :  invalid extract field for extract source error

Comment: `select extract(day from last_day(add_months(sysdate,1))) Last_day,  to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,1)),'dd.mm.yyyy') next_month  from dual;`

Comment: SELECT extract(day from last_day(add_months(:datum_dokumenta,1))) 
   ||'.'|| (extract(month from :datum_dokumenta)+1)||'.'||extract(year from :datum_dokumenta) from dual; 
in the first line is your extract but still doesnt work i get : ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
30076. 00000 -  "invalid extract field for extract source

Answer (score 2):

Using `(extract(month from :date)+1)` will not work for a date in December as you will end up with a `13`th month. Similarly, `extract(year from :date)` will get you the current year - which may not be correct if you are looking for the last day of the next month from December and the result should be the January of the following year.

You do not need to extract all the fields separately, you can do it all in a single statement:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS( :date, 1 ) ),
         'DD.MM.YYYY'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```